# Show column from joined table even if it has no matchings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am joining table R5PARTS and R5STOCK with R5TRANSLINES.

I want to extract MAX(TRL_DATE) when the transaction type TRL_TYPE = 'I' and matches the join conditions (from R5TRANSLINES)
This way, I can get when a part was last used.

What problem do I have? 
Not all parts have been used, so they do not have rows on R5TRANSLINES with this type of transaction 'I'.
Then logically, when I filter using WHERE TRL_TYPE = 'I' I am getting no results for that parts.

Is there a workarround I can use so ALL SELECTED LINES show a row with TRL_TYPE = 'I' even if it does not exist on the table R5TRANSLINES? (In this case, the field TRL_DATE would be fixed like... '01-01-1900')

From my research, I think it should work with a simple 'left join R5TRANSLINES', but it doesn't...

This is the code I have:

```
declare @startdate date = '2010-01-01'
declare @enddate date = '2020-01-01'

SELECT      RS.STO_PART, Rs.STO_PART_ORG, RS.STO_STORE, RP.PAR_DESC, ISNULL(RS.STO_AVGPRICE, 0) as 'STO_AVGPRICE',

            MAX(RT.TRL_DATE) as 'LAST_USED', RT.TRL_TYPE

FROM        R5STOCK RS inner join R5PARTS RP on RP.PAR_CODE = RS.STO_PART and RS.STO_PART_ORG = RP.PAR_ORG            
            left join R5TRANSLINES RT on (RT.TRL_PART = RP.PAR_CODE and RP.PAR_ORG = RT.TRL_PART_ORG and TRL_TYPE = 'I')

WHERE       RP.PAR_NOTUSED != '+' and RS.STO_STORE in ('116-01', '138-05', '156-01', '216-01', '228-01', '282-01')      and TRL_PART = '116-MEU-NR 100-25-3.3547'

GROUP BY    RP.PAR_CODE, RS.STO_PART, RS.STO_PART_ORG, RS.STO_STORE, RP.PAR_DESC, RS.STO_AVGPRICE, RT.TRL_TYPE
ORDER BY    RS.STO_PART
```

EDIT: Query simplified and added all advices from the "duplicate" post. But still can't get to show all rows needed.

Comment: Show us the LEFT JOIN query as well. And qualify all columns, i.e. like `tab1.colx`.

Comment: UNION to a second query where you only get rows that have no matching parts. The GROUP BY will specifically exclude null returns on the aggregate.

Comment: @jarlh edited.
The left join basically was adding LEFT JOIN R5TRANSLINES where there is an INNER JOIN now.

Comment: I simplified the query and added a left join and the condition on the ON clausule, but still can't get to show all rows needed.